# Submitting the same (Runnable) command multiple times to executor service in Java

Tags: java

I want to schedule the same command in a parallel fashion using executor service in Java. I wrote a wrapper over thread pool executor, which takes the parallel count to schedule the command as parameter and in a for loop, schedules the command(i.e. same instance multiple times).

Is this approach correct? Is there any suggested way of doing this? I am using spring to create these beans.

Comment: why not use a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html   check the methods "scheduleAtFixedRate" and "scheduleWithFixedDelay"

Comment: I am using Scheduled Executor service and scheduling at fixed rate. But instead of one command being scheduled, I want it to be scheduled in parallel fashion e.g. it should run 5 times at 1st sec, 5 times at 2nd sec, 5 times at 3rd sec and not once at 1st sec, once at 2nd sec ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`ScheduledExecuterService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) as follows:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduledExecutorTest {

    private final static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("executed");
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        Thread.sleep(10000);
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

This will execute the `run` method every second starting immediately.

With this approach you can add it multiple times to the `scheduledExecuterService`:

```
Runnable command = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("executed");
    }
};
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(command, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I have implemented runnable interface and that is the command I want to schedule in parallel fashion. The above implementation just schedules the same command with only one instance.  instead of one command being scheduled, I want it to be scheduled in parallel fashion e.g. it should run 5 times at 1st sec, 5 times at 2nd sec, 5 times at 3rd sec and not once at 1st sec, once at 2nd sec ..

Comment: you can use the approach I added now

Comment: The approach you suggested is exactly what I am doing! Just wanted to validate if that is correct or not.